# How to obtain metadata about the current executor(s), Apache-Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, metadata, executor

I would like to get as much information as possible from within the executor, while it is executing, but can't seem to find any information on how to accomplish that other than by using the Web UI. For example, it would be useful to know which file is being processed by which executor, and when.

I need this flexibility for debugging, but cannot find any information about it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want it from an RDD? If not, then you can focus on SparkListener and ExecutorInfo.

Comment: Yes, I do want it from RDD, but I will investigate the SparkListener and ExecutorInfo (THANK YOU!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to accomplish it is to mapPartitionsWithContext

Example code:

```
  import org.apache.spark.TaskContext

    val a = sc.parallelize(1 to 9, 3)

    def myfunc(tc: TaskContext, iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[Int] = {
    tc.addOnCompleteCallback(() => println( 
    "Partition: " + tc.partitionId + 
    ", AttemptID: " + tc.attemptId
    )
    )
    iter.toList.filter(_ % 2 == 0).iterator 
    }

   a.mapPartitionsWithContext(myfunc)
   a.collect
```

API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.TaskContext

However, this does not answer the question about how to see which file was processed, and when.